# LaTeX table does not extend to the next page

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a long table that doesn't extend to the next page. I am using a journal template. I tried using `longtable` but it didn't work. I tried `table`, `tabularx` and `longtable` but it didn't work as it doesn't adjust the width properly. The table stays on one page and half of the table disappears.

Kindly check my code and let me know what is the mistake. Thank you very much in advance.

```
\begin{longtable}{\fulllength}{CCCCCCCC}
%\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-\extralength}{0cm}
        \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
        %\begin{tabularx}{\fulllength}{CCCCCCCC}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Sensing material}   & \textbf{Structure type}   & \textbf{Fabrication technique}     & \textbf{Temperature (\textdegree C)} & \textbf{VOCs detected}    & \textbf{Detection range}     & \textbf{Data analysis technique}     & \textbf{Ref.}\\
            \midrule
SnO\textsubscript{2} and WO\textsubscript{3}    & Villi-like nano structure         & Electron beam evaporation         & 212   & nitrogen oxide, ammonia, ethanol, acetone, toluene, benzene, carbon monoxide,         & 899 ppt – 10 ppm          & PCA           & \cite{RN5229}\\
                   \midrule
MOS (NiO, CuO, Cr\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3}, SnO\textsubscript{2} and WO\textsubscript{3}) & Nano pattern of multi-array sensing           & Lithography           & 380   & toluene, nitrogen oxide, ammonia, ethanol, acetone, hexane, propanol          & 5 ppm         & PCA           & \cite{RN5230}\\
                   \midrule
SnO\textsubscript{2}    & Nanowire gradient         & Vapor solid method            & 326   & isopropyl alcohol, ethanol, carbon monoxide           & 2 – 10 ppm            & LDA           & \cite{RN5133}\\
                  \midrule
Pd/SnO\textsubscript{2} & Nanowire sensor array         & Vapor solid           & 150   & isopropyl alcohol         & 1 – 50 ppm            & LDA           & \cite{RN5134}\\
            \midrule
TiO\textsubscript{2}, SnO\textsubscript{2}, ITO, WO\textsubscript{3}    & Nanorod array         & Oblique angle deposition          & 250   & hydrogen, carbon monoxide, nitrogen dioxide           & 10 – 200 ppm          & -         & \cite{RN5132}\\
                   \midrule
Si-SiO\textsubscript{2}, Pd-SiO\textsubscript{2}, Pt-SiO\textsubscript{2}, Ti-SiO\textsubscript{2}  & Microwire sensor chip         & Flexible flame spray pyrolysis            & 400  & formaldehyde, acetone, ethanol, ammonia            & 3 ppb         & -         & \cite{RN483}\\
                   \midrule
WO\textsubscript{3} & Nanofibers        & Electrospinning           & 350   & hydrogen sulfide, acetone         & 1 – 5 ppm         & PCA           & \cite{RN5131}\\
                  \midrule
Cu\textsubscript{2}O    & Nanospheres           & silanization          & 180   & ethanol, ethylacetate, toluene, hexane, tetrahydrofuran           & 25 – 200 ppm          & PCA           & \cite{RN5231}\\
            \midrule
Gold    & Nano-islands          & In-situ iterative seeding and growth          & RT   & acetone, ethanol, propionaldehyde, acetophenone, benzyl alcohol, benzaldehyde & 1 – 1000 ppm           & PCA           & \cite{RN5232}\\
                   \midrule
Pt, Pd-doped SnO\textsubscript{2}/RGO   & Nanohybrids           & Hydrothermal          & 180   & hydrogen, hydrogen sulfide, nitrogen dioxide          & 0.04 – 40 ppm         & PCA, LDA, Hierarchical Cluster Analysis           & \cite{RN5233}\\
                   \midrule
Thermo-cycled MOS sensors   & MOS films         & Thermal deposition            & 260 - 290   & hexane, butyl acetate           & 50 – 175 ppm          & -         & \cite{RN287}\\
                  \midrule
Commercial PEN3, CAPINose   & TGS sensors           & -         & RT   & ethanol            & 10 vol.\%         & Average resistance            & \cite{RN286}\\
            \midrule
SnO\textsubscript{2}, WO\textsubscript{3}, ZnO, In\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3}   & Nanofilms         & Screen printing           & 26 - 426   & formaldehyde, carbon monoxide, nitrogen dioxide, toluene, ammonia        & 0.6 – 1000 ppm            & -         & \cite{RN276}\\
                   \midrule
ZnTiO\textsubscript{3}  & Nanoarrays            & Hydrothermal, CVD         & 350   & acetone           & 1.2 – 12.5 ppm            & -         & \cite{RN296}\\
                  \midrule
Au/SnO\textsubscript{2}, Pt/SnO\textsubscript{2}, Ni/SnO\textsubscript{2}, ITO/SnO\textsubscript{2} & Multiplexed nanotube arrays           & Spray pyrolysis           & RT   & hydrogen, benzene, nitrogen dioxide            & 50 – 4000 ppm         & LVA           & \cite{RN5224}\\
                   \midrule
Warwick OLFaction (WOLF) E-nose & MEMS MOS-based commercial thick and thin film sensors     & -         & RT   & acetone, 1-propanol, iso-propanol, iso-butylene            & 2 – 10 ppm            & PCA           & \cite{RN120}\\
                   \midrule
Pt, Cu, and Ag decorated TiO\textsubscript{2} and ZnO functionalized GaN    & Nanowire          & Lithography, CVD, Chemical Etching            & RT   & nitrogen dioxide, sulfur dioxide, hydrogen, ethanol            & 0.1 – 10000 ppm           & PCA, SVM, k-NN, Decision Tree         & \cite{RN5237}\\
                  \midrule
Au decorated WO\textsubscript{3}, SnO\textsubscript{2} and NiO  & Thin films, nanostructures            & electron-beam evaporation         & 100 – 300   & acetone, toluene, ammonia, hydrogen sulfide         & 10 ppm            & PCA           & \cite{RN5238}\\
                   \midrule
Commercial MOS sensors  & TGS sensors           & -         & RT   & ethanol, acetone           & -         & partial least squares discriminant analysis           & \cite{RN5239}\\
                   \midrule
Commercial MOS sensors  & TGS Sensors           & -         & RT   & nitrogen dioxide, carbon monoxide          & 0 – 50 ppm            & PCA, C-means clustering, back propagation neural network          & \cite{RN5240}\\
                  \midrule
Pure and Fe-doped In\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3} & nanofibers            & Electrospinning           & 250 – 450    & benzene, xylene, toluene, ethanol, formaldehyde            & 0.1 – 1000 ppm            & PCA           & \cite{RN5137}\\
            \bottomrule
        %\end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    %\noindent{\footnotesize{* Tables may have a footer.}}
%\end{table}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you add the `\documentclass` and necessary packages, so that this is a complete example?  Then we can copy and paste what you're doing.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 if you have questions on that process.

Comment: you can't do this _inside_ th etable `\begin{adjustwidth}{-\extralength}{0cm}
        \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` (well you can but it will not affect the outer table)  and you have already used `C` (with no definition shown)

Comment: You wrote, "I am using a journal template." Which one would it be?

Comment: How or where is `\fulllength` defined?

Comment: @Mico, the journal is Chemosensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you load the [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) package and employ its eponymous environment, which combines the capabilities of the `longtable` and `tabularx` environments. And, by all means, do load a package such as [mhchem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) and start writing chemical compound names in a streamlined and easy-to-read fashion. E.g., `\ce{Cr2O3}` instead of `Cr\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3}`. Finally, I see no need for all those heavy-handed `\midrule` directives; visual separation via `\addlinespace` directives works at least as well.

You didn't indicate which document class you employ or how wide and tall the textblock is. The following code therefore uses the defaults for the basic `article` document class. Do please indicate which document class you employ.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%% define some additional hyphenation points:
\hyphenation{di-oxide hydro-thermal mon-oxide micro-wire 
nano-arrays nano-fi-bers nano-films nano-hybrids 
nano-spheres nano-struc-tures nano-tube nano-wire nano-wires
prop-anol}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\nobreakdash' macro
\usepackage{mhchem}   % for '\ce' macro
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
% column type that suppresses full justificaiton, but allows hyphenation:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 

\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} LLLL LLL l @{}}

%% headers and footers
\toprule
Sensing material & 
Structure type & 
Fabrication technique & 
Temperature (\textdegree C) & 
VOCs detected & 
Detection range & 
Data analysis technique & 
Ref.\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (\textit{cont'd on following page})}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\ce{SnO3} and \ce{WO3} & Villi-like nano structure & Electron beam evaporation & 212 & nitrogen oxide, ammonia, ethanol, acetone, toluene, benzene, carbon monoxide, & 899 ppt--10 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN5229}\\
\addlinespace
MOS (\ce{NiO}, \ce{CuO}, \ce{Cr2O3}, \ce{SnO3} and \ce{WO3}) & Nano pattern of multi-array sensing & Lithography & 380 & toluene, nitrogen oxide, ammonia, ethanol, acetone, hexane, propanol & 5 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN5230}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{SnO3} & Nanowire gradient & Vapor solid method & 326 & isopropyl alcohol, ethanol, carbon monoxide & 2--10 ppm & LDA & \cite{RN5133}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{Pd}\slash \ce{SnO3} & Nanowire sensor array & Vapor solid & 150 & isopropyl alcohol & 1--50 ppm & LDA & \cite{RN5134}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{TiO2}, \ce{SnO3}, ITO, \ce{WO3} & Nanorod array & Oblique angle deposition & 250 & hydrogen, carbon monoxide, nitrogen dioxide & 10--200 ppm & -- & \cite{RN5132}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{Si}-\ce{SiO2}, \ce{Pd}-\ce{SiO2}, \ce{Pt}-\ce{SiO2}, \ce{Ti}-\ce{SiO2} & Microwire sensor chip & Flexible flame spray pyrolysis & 400 & formaldehyde, acetone, ethanol, ammonia & 3 ppb & -- & \cite{RN483}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{WO3} & Nanofibers & Electrospinning & 350 & hydrogen sulfide, acetone & 1--5 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN5131}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{Cu2O} & Nanospheres & silanization & 180 & ethanol, ethylacetate, toluene, hexane, tetrahydrofuran & 25--200 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN5231}\\
\addlinespace
Gold & Nano-islands & In-situ iterative seeding and growth & RT & acetone, ethanol, propionaldehyde, acetophenone, benzyl alcohol, benzaldehyde & 1--1000 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN5232}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{Pt}, \ce{Pd}-doped \ce{SnO3}\slash RGO & Nanohybrids & Hydrothermal & 180 & hydrogen, hydrogen sulfide, nitrogen dioxide & 0.04--40 ppm & PCA, LDA, Hierarchical Cluster Analysis & \cite{RN5233}\\
\addlinespace
Thermo-cycled MOS sensors & MOS films & Thermal deposition & 260--290 & hexane, butyl acetate & 50--175 ppm & -- & \cite{RN287}\\
\addlinespace
Commercial PEN3, CAPINose & TGS sensors & -- & RT & ethanol & 10 vol.\% & Average resistance & \cite{RN286}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{SnO3}, \ce{WO3}, \ce{ZnO}, \ce{In2O3} & Nanofilms & Screen printing & 26--426 & formaldehyde, carbon monoxide, nitrogen dioxide, toluene, ammonia & 0.6--1000 ppm & -- & \cite{RN276}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{ZiTiO3} & Nanoarrays & Hydrothermal, CVD & 350 & acetone & 1.2--12.5 ppm & -- & \cite{RN296}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{Au}\slash \ce{SnO3}, \ce{Pt}\slash \ce{SnO3}, \ce{Ni}\slash \ce{SnO3}, ITO\slash \ce{SnO3} & Multiplexed nanotube arrays & Spray pyrolysis & RT & hydrogen, benzene, nitrogen dioxide & 50--4000 ppm & LVA & \cite{RN5224}\\
\addlinespace
Warwick OLFaction (WOLF) E-nose & MEMS MOS-based commercial thick and thin film sensors & -- & RT & acetone, 1\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}propanol, iso-propanol, iso-butylene & 2--10 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN120}\\
\addlinespace
\ce{Pt}, \ce{Cu}, and \ce{Ag} decorated \ce{TiO2} and \ce{ZnO} functionalized \ce{GaN} & Nanowire & Lithography, CVD, Chemical Etching & RT & nitrogen dioxide, sulfur dioxide, hydrogen, ethanol & 0.1--10000 ppm & PCA, SVM, k-NN, Decision Tree & \cite{RN5237}\\
\addlinespace
Au decorated \ce{WO3}, \ce{SnO3} and \ce{NiO} & Thin films, nanostructures & electron-beam evaporation & 100--300 & acetone, toluene, ammonia, hydrogen sulfide & 10 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN5238}\\
\addlinespace
Commercial MOS sensors & TGS sensors & -- & RT & ethanol, acetone & -- & partial least squares discriminant analysis & \cite{RN5239}\\
\addlinespace
Commercial MOS sensors & TGS Sensors & -- & RT & nitrogen dioxide, carbon monoxide & 0--50 ppm & PCA, \mbox{C-means} clustering, back propagation neural network & \cite{RN5240}\\
\addlinespace
Pure and \ce{Fe}-doped \ce{In2O3} & Nanofibers & Electrospinning & 250--450 & benzene, xylene, toluene, ethanol, formaldehyde & 0.1--1000 ppm & PCA & \cite{RN5137}\\

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Mico, Thank you very much for your time. It works now but I am having a problem with adding the table caption. 

By the here is the document class in the journal template. `\documentclass[journal,article,submit,pdftex,moreauthors]{Definitions/mdpi} `

Comment: @Zain - Thanks for providing these additional pieces of information. Adding a table caption shoud be done as with any `longtable` setup: Provide separate `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` statements, and issue a `\caption` statement in the `\endfirsthead` group. Please consult the user guide of the [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package for more information. (You may have noticed that my answer does not provide separate `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` directives. This is precisely because you initially didn't indicate you would wish having a caption.)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your help. It is all good now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Unfortunately you not provide MWE (Minimqal Working Example), a small but complete document. Consequently page layout and used document class are unknown.
- If you refer to use "classic" packages for writing long tables, use of the `xltabular` package is good choose, but also exist newer quite versatile `tabularray` package based on LaTeX3, which offers new features in writing tables (for details see package documentations for details).
- Your table is quite wide, so for nice looks it need wider ˙\textwidth`(which can be defined by`geometry`package or you may consider to write your table in the landscape page orientation. Beside this, for better spacing text in table cells, I would recommend to use`\small` font size.
- For units and quantities I suggest to use ˙siunitx` package.
- To make some column headers narrower, for then I would use abbreviations and their meaning explain in table notes.
- By reducing lines spread in table for about 10% is possible to fit table on two pages.
- So, possible solution for your table can be also the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%% define some additional hyphenation points:
\hyphenation{electro-spinning di-oxide hydro-thermal mon-oxide micro-wire
             nano-arrays nano-fi-bers nano-films nano-hybrids
             nano-spheres nano-struc-tures nano-tube nano-wire nano-wires
             prop-anol}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}   % for '\ce' macro

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmah, booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\sisetup{range-units = single, range-phrase = --}
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none,     % <---
note{a} = {T: Temperature},
note{b} = {DAT: Data Analysis Techniques},
                ]{colsep  = 3pt,     
                  colspec = {@{} *{3}{X[l]} c X[1.8, l] *{2}{X[l]} l @{}},
                  cells   = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont},
                  row{3-Z}= {rowsep=5pt},
                  row{1}  = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries,m}, 
                  rowhead = 1, 
                  }
%%  table body
    \toprule
{Sensing\\ material} 
    &   {Structure\\ type}
        &   {Fabrication\\ technique}
            &   {T\TblrNote{a}\\ (\unit{\degreeCelsius})}
                &   {VOCs\\ detected}
                    &   Detection range
                        &   DAT\TblrNote{b}
                            &   Ref.     \\
    \midrule
\ce{SnO3} and \ce{WO3} & Villi-like nano structure & Electron beam evaporation & 212 & nitrogen oxide, ammonia, ethanol, acetone, toluene, benzene, carbon monoxide, & \qty{899}{ppt} -- \qty{10}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN5229}\\

MOS (\ce{NiO}, \ce{CuO}, \ce{Cr2O3}, \ce{SnO3} and \ce{WO3}) & Nano pattern of multi-array sensing & Lithography & 380 & toluene, nitrogen oxide, ammonia, ethanol, acetone, hexane, propanol & \qty{5}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN5230}\\

\ce{SnO3} & Nanowire gradient & Vapor solid method & 326 & isopropyl alcohol, ethanol, carbon monoxide & \qtyrange{2}{10}{ppm} & LDA & \cite{RN5133}\\

\ce{Pd}\slash \ce{SnO3} & Nanowire sensor array & Vapor solid & 150 & isopropyl alcohol & \qtyrange{1}{50}{ppm} & LDA & \cite{RN5134}\\

\ce{TiO2}, \ce{SnO3}, ITO, \ce{WO3} & Nanorod array & Oblique angle deposition & 250 & hydrogen, carbon monoxide, nitrogen dioxide & \qtyrange{10}{200}{ppm} & -- & \cite{RN5132}\\

\ce{Si}-\ce{SiO2}, \ce{Pd}-\ce{SiO2}, \ce{Pt}-\ce{SiO2}, \ce{Ti}-\ce{SiO2} & Microwire sensor chip & Flexible flame spray pyrolysis & 400 & formaldehyde, acetone, ethanol, ammonia & \qty{3}{ppm} & -- & \cite{RN483}\\

\ce{WO3} & Nanofibers & Electro\-spinning & 350 & hydrogen sulfide, acetone & \qtyrange{1}{5}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN5131}\\

\ce{Cu2O} & Nanospheres & silanization & 180 & ethanol, ethylacetate, toluene, hexane, tetrahydrofuran & \qtyrange{25}{200}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN5231}\\

Gold & Nano-islands & In-situ iterative seeding and growth & RT & acetone, ethanol, propionaldehyde, acetophenone, benzyl alcohol, benzaldehyde & \qtyrange{1}{1000}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN5232}\\

\ce{Pt}, \ce{Pd}-doped \ce{SnO3}\slash RGO & Nanohybrids & Hydro\-thermal & 180 & hydrogen, hydrogen sulfide, nitrogen dioxide & \qtyrange{0.04}{40}{ppm} & PCA, LDA, Hierarchical Cluster Analysis & \cite{RN5233}\\

Thermo-cycled MOS sensors & MOS films & Thermal deposition & 260--290 & hexane, butyl acetate & \qtyrange{50}{175}{ppm} & -- & \cite{RN287}\\

Commercial PEN3, CAPINose & TGS sensors & -- & RT & ethanol & 10 vol.\% & Average resistance & \cite{RN286}\\

\ce{SnO3}, \ce{WO3}, \ce{ZnO}, \ce{In2O3} & Nanofilms & Screen printing & 26--426 & formaldehyde, carbon monoxide, nitrogen dioxide, toluene, ammonia & \qtyrange{0.6}{1000}{ppm} & -- & \cite{RN276}\\

\ce{ZiTiO3} & Nanoarrays & Hydro\-thermal, CVD & 350 & acetone & \qtyrange{1.2}{12.5}{ppm} & -- & \cite{RN296}\\

\ce{Au}\slash \ce{SnO3}, \ce{Pt}\slash \ce{SnO3}, \ce{Ni}\slash \ce{SnO3}, ITO\slash \ce{SnO3} & Multiplexed nanotube arrays & Spray pyrolysis & RT & hydrogen, benzene, nitrogen dioxide & \qtyrange{50}{4000}{ppm} & LVA & \cite{RN5224}\\

Warwick OLFaction (WOLF) E-nose & MEMS MOS-based commercial thick and thin film sensors & -- & RT & acetone, 1\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}propanol, iso-propanol, iso-butylene & \qtyrange{2}{10}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN120}\\

\ce{Pt}, \ce{Cu}, and \ce{Ag} decorated \ce{TiO2} and \ce{ZnO} functionalized \ce{GaN} & Nanowire & Lithography, CVD, Chemical Etching & RT & nitrogen dioxide, sulfur dioxide, hydrogen, ethanol & \qtyrange{0.1}{10000}{ppm} & PCA, SVM, k-NN, Decision Tree & \cite{RN5237}\\

Au decorated \ce{WO3}, \ce{SnO3} and \ce{NiO} & Thin films, nanostructures & electron-beam evaporation & 100--300 & acetone, toluene, ammonia, hydrogen sulfide & \qty{10}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN5238}\\

Commercial MOS sensors & TGS sensors & -- & RT & ethanol, acetone & -- & partial least squares discriminant analysis & \cite{RN5239}\\

Commercial MOS sensors & TGS Sensors & -- & RT & nitrogen dioxide, carbon monoxide & \qtyrange{0}{50}{ppm} & PCA, \mbox{C-means} clustering, back propagation neural network & \cite{RN5240}\\

Pure and \ce{Fe}-doped \ce{In2O3} & Nanofibers & Electro\-spinning & 250--450 & benzene, xylene, toluene, ethanol, formaldehyde & \qtyrange{0.1}{1000}{ppm} & PCA & \cite{RN5137} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]